# Is it possible to increase voltage from a power supply without incuring great current lose

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage-regulator

I have a 24V 4.5 amp(108 Watt) power supply.  I know most Voltage regulators take a higher voltage and regulate it to a lower voltage.

Is there a way to increase the voltage of the 24V 4.5 amp(108) power supply to 36V(3 amp) or 48V(2.25 amp) while still allowing the same amount of power output(108 watts)?

Can you boost the voltage up and then put a voltage regulator on it?

Comment: @CamilStaps you're right I mainly wanted to get the idea of increasing the voltage while still keeping a relative similar power level, i'm mainly not aware of any methods of increasing a voltage like this.  I know small IC that can be used to increase a voltage, but are limited to ~50mA or something

Comment: What you'll want to search for is a boost converter.

Comment: just looked it up, there are a few IC that can handle this, but they cost a lot $30+. are there another way with smaller component cost?

Comment: Your subject says "without losing current" (which is not possible, even with ideal components), while the question body asks about boosting voltage without losing "power output" (which is possible with ideal components). These are very different questions: power and current are not the same thing. Please edit to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: good to know your right i'll do that from now on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TPS55340](http://www.ti.com/product/tps55340) is a monolithic non-synchronous switching regulator with integrated 5-Amp, 40-Volt power switch. It can be configured in several standard switching-regulator topologies, including boost, SEPIC and isolated flyback. The device has a wide input voltage range to support applications with input voltage from multi-cell batteries or regulated 3.3-V, 5-V, 12-V, and 24-V power rails.
Features an Internal 5-A, 40-V Low-Side MOSFET Switch, 2.9-V to 32-V Input Voltage Range. Vout up to 38 Volts.

It is under 5 dollars in individual price, but you'd have to design a board, and get the small parts needed.

There are more that can do the same, but that has an internal switch. Boost regulators with external switches can carry more amperage and some could boost the voltage higher, with good efficiency >90%.

But the majority of the cost in Completed Modules, is you are paying for a working design, testing, and manufacture of them.

Comment: THIS PART IS AWESOME.  I have search the web for higher voltage power supplies, but they don't have something this.